# What are the requirements for running a Dash Masternode?

Tags: dash, dash-masternode

Dash Masternodes allow for InstantSend transactions and are paid a portion of Dash's mining revenue. What requirements does a Masternode need to fulfill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dash Masternodes are archival full nodes. They enable the PrivateSend and InstantSend feature. Masternodes get to vote on funding and governance proposals. Masternodes are paid for these services with 45% of the mining reward.

A Masternode needs to put up a collateral of 1,000 Dash, have a dedicated IP address and may not be offline for more than 1 hour in 24h. Anyone can run a Masternode.